# How can I serialize an object where the object has a Delegate created from an Action?

Tags: c#, serialization

How can I serialize an object where the object has a `Delegate` created from an `Action` such that I can deserialize the object and the `Delegate` is still subscribed?

Here is the class code:

```
[Serializable]
public class TestClass
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> refresh;
    public void AddHandlerForAction()
    {
        var methodInfo = this.GetType().GetMethod("RefreshMethodNoParamaters");
        Action action = (Action)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action), this, methodInfo);

        var eventInfo = this.GetType().GetEvent("refresh");

        var handlerType = eventInfo.EventHandlerType;
        var eventParams = handlerType.GetMethod("Invoke").GetParameters();

        var parameters = eventParams.Select(p => Expression.Parameter(p.ParameterType, "x"));
        var body = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(action), action.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke"));
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda(body, parameters.ToArray());
        Delegate d = Delegate.CreateDelegate(handlerType, lambda.Compile(), "Invoke", false);

        eventInfo.AddEventHandler(this, d);
    }
    public virtual object Clone()
    {
        Type type = this.GetType();
        if (!type.IsSerializable)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The type must be serializable.", "source");
        }

        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, null))
        {
            return this.GetType().GetMethod("GetDefaultGeneric").MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(this, null);
        }
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(stream, this);
            stream.Position = 0;
            var clone = Convert.ChangeType(formatter.Deserialize(stream), type);
            return clone;
        }
    }
    public void RaiseEvent()
    {
        EventHandler<EventArgs> eventHandler = refresh;
        if (eventHandler != null)
        {
            eventHandler(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
    public void RefreshMethodNoParamaters()
    {

    }
}
```

Here is the code that performs an exception:

```
var testClass = new TestClass();
testClass.AddHandlerForAction();
testClass.RaiseEvent();

var clone = testClass.Clone();
```

The exception occurs at this line of code:

```
formatter.Serialize(stream, this);
```

Here is the exception:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot serialize delegates over unmanaged
>   function pointers, dynamic methods or methods outside the delegate
>   creator's assembly.

The objective of the code is to subscribe to an `Event` where the method that is called when the `Event` is raised has no parameters.

Comment: Avoid doing that it will come back to byte you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40780504/66372. This answer explains the problem very well and has a recommendation for an alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1133465/66372.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to serialize that class you can use `[NonSerialized]` attribute. But you will need to use attribute target (field):

```
[field: NonSerialized]
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> refresh;
```

Here is more about [attribute specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664616(VS.71).aspx)

EDIT:

if you need to keep the attached event (and this will work for your example, but not for the long-term storage) you can populate the event handler in your clone function:

```
public virtual object Clone()
{
    //...
    var clone = Convert.ChangeType(formatter.Deserialize(stream), type);

    (clone as TestClass).refresh = this.refresh;

    return clone;    
}
```

But for my preference it is a very hacky way...

Comment: After the object is serialized, when the event is raised, the action is not called.

Comment: @user3736648 updated my answer with a possible solution