# C# Save a delegate in Microsoft Access

Tags: c#, ms-access, delegates

I wan't to create instances of the following class, and save them in a Microsoft Access DataBase.

```
public class Foo
{
    Func<bool> DelegateToSave { get; set; }

    string Name { get; set; }
    string FullName { get; set; }
    int Priority { get; set; }
    Foo Parent { get; set; }
}
```

How can a delegate be saved in Microsoft Access?

Comment: you'd have to do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132702/could-we-save-delegates-in-a-file-c

Comment: Not easily. I suspect you are trying to do something you don't actually need to do. Are you saying your application won't have a `Foo` Type and you want to create one at runtime?

Comment: I will have a Tree Data Structure of Foos that needs to be received from Access. However, every Foo will have its own delegate.